# POSTing GradeObjects always results in 400

Tags: desire2learn

I'm trying to `POST` Numeric GradeObjects to D2L, but no matter what I include in the data of the `POST` request, I get a `400` error (Bad request, my data is invalid). The D2L system log has no details about what could have gone wrong, and the response body is empty.

Up until about 2 weeks ago the same code was successful at `POST`ing new GradeObjects.

Any ideas on how I debug?

Comment: Since you were once able to do this, and now are not, I would encourage you to open a support incident with D2L's support desk through your Approved Support Contact, or D2L Account or Partner Manager; I would also advise you to characterize this as a potential defect with the Valence Learning Framework APIs so that it gets triaged appropriately and placed with the right group.

Comment: Also, things to consider here: has your back-end service had an update (service pack) or upgrade (new major release)? what version of the LE are you using? were the old working calls and the new not-working calls made against the same course? made by the same calling user context? calling user enrolled in course(s) in all cases? if you can trap a working call and not-working call using Fiddler or the like and submit it with your support incident that can help a lot.

Comment: Finally -- can you include an example here of, at least, your JSON grade object you're passing in that's failing, and perhaps even a copy-paste of the entire HTTP request packet you're sending (with your App ID/UserID values occluded)?

Comment: Thanks for the help Viktor. Our back-end has not changed, and we noticed the problem mid-sprint so it was working with the same backend before. We're using LE API v1.0 targeting D2L suite v9.4.1, and we have not specified any changes to API versions. I'll try to get an example of the HTTP request we're making the the response we receieve.

Comment: @ViktorHaag Is it no longer possible to POST GradeObjects without a GradeObjectCategory?

Comment: Hmm: if you're providing the GradeObjectCategory ID as `null`, then you can try providing it as `0` instead. This may be a known defect, and providing a value of `0` may function as a workaround for you.